# Android:Text is not displaying for textview

Tags: android, text, textview

Text is not getting displayed for the textview and here is the code.

I could able to see only image but no text.

```
        textView.setText(navItem.getTitleEN());

         if (position == MULTIMEDIA_POSITION && tabletSize) {
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, getImage(context, iconName + "_active_tablet"), 0, 0);

        }
```

Xml is here

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/menu_item"
android:background="@drawable/mainnav_bg_1st"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_item_height"
android:textColor="@color/selector_navigation_text"
android:gravity="center"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:drawablePadding="-10dp"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/nav_item_text_size"/>
```

Comment: Try to remove some code from xml, or the 'if{}' things. Then see when it works.

Answer (score 1):

To set the text you need to call `textView.setText("your string");`, I don't see you are calling this method in the code you provided.

Comment: I am not getting the text because of image size  i guess :)

Comment: yeah, I would suggest to display the image to the right of the text and see if the text is there. If it does appear then you would need to fix the image size

Answer (score 1):

Check if parameter @dimen/nav_item_height is sufficient for displaying both icon and text

Comment: yes,if i increase this height more then i m getting it but still there is a lot of space between image and text .for other items i m getting properly in the menu.so without increasing the height cant we do this??

Comment: Without changing the element size it can be done by shrinking the image or decreasing of drawablePadding attribute. Another way is to follow Joel Min's advise and move image to the left or right side of TextView.